# tightvnc crashes upon the second click to the Launcher's Terminal icon

Tags: ubuntu, tightvnc

I am running tightvnc (version 1.3.9) on ubuntu 12.04.

When run **locally** the ubuntu desktop has a feature wherein if two Terminals are open but obscured by a third application, the first click on the Launcher's Terminal icon will bring to the foreground the most recently used Terminal.  The second click at the same place on the Launcher will cause ubuntu to conveniently and in a slick, animated manner display two small window representations of the Terminals and the user at that point can click to select a Terminal.  At that point the selected Terminal will be displayed in the foreground at the normal size and will take the focus.

**Remotely**, this second click behaviour does not work in tightvnc and in fact it causes the VNC server to malfunction and terminate (it no longer appears in the process list) and the VNC session abruptly ends.

How do I fix this problem?  It is easily reproducible.

Comment: Which DE do you use?

Comment: I'm using the ubuntu desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Experienced similar issue. According to [this](http://pietercvdmlinux.blogspot.ru/2010/07/running-tightvncserver-on-ubuntu-1004.html) link you should try tightvnc 1.3.10. Didn't try it though because didn't have root privileges on server.